# Download file from BLOB field 

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, base64, blob

I have an application where I store a file(doc, pdf, xls, txt) on a BLOB field in a DB2 database(encoded in base64). Now I have have to download the file, and I'm only having success when I download a text file. When I download the other files, I can't decode them properly.

I tried inserting the content on the BLOB file using two ways:

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,RW5yaWNvIEJlcmdhbW8=
```

AND

```
RW5yaWNvIEJlcmdhbW8=
```

In both cases the result is the same for me.

And the code I'm using to download and decode these files is:

`fileDownload.jsp`:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.misc.*"%>

<%
    String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
    String fileType = request.getParameter("fileType");
    String fileContent = b64Decode(request.getParameter("fileContent"));

    response.setContentType(fileType);
    //response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""
            + fileName + "\"");
    response.setContentLength((int) fileContent.length());

    try {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(fileContent);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
        //InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while (in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
            sos.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        in.close();
        sos.flush();
        sos.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
%>

<%!public String b64Decode(String msg) {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] decodedBytes = null;
        try {
            decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(decodedBytes);
    }%>
```

I do believe the problem is with the encoding, but I have no clue on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't use a JSP for this.  JSPs are intended to render things like HTML, not binary data.  The JSP container will do its own character encoding and content-type shenanigans behind the scenes, which can conflict with your intent.

You should rewrite this as a servlet, instead of as a JSP, and it should be more predictable.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the fast answer. I have never worked with JSP/Servlets before, so in this tecnology I don't know the best ways to do these tasks, would you know a piece of code for me to work on?

Comment: The problem unfortunately is still here. Detail is that, my blob is a DataURL, I spent the whole day searching for a way to convert back dataURL to File using JSP, Java or Javascript..but still no answers found. Do you ever experienced this problem?